# How to get the profile picture of gmail user using email

Tags: javascript, html, email, gmail

Is there a way to get the profile picture of gmail user using email? Without authentication? 
How can I get the name also?

I used this url,

```
http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/{some_email_address]?alt=json
```

to get the picture using a browser.
But not allowed to use it with localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `&callback=<some name>` to use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Comment: Where will I put that?

Answer (score 0):

What JavaScript platform are you using?

For example in nodejs you can use the request package with the example code below:

```
const request= require('request'); 

request({ url: 'http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/{email here}?alt=json', method: 'Get', }, (err, res, body) => { console.log(body); });
```

Comment: I am just using knockout js and jquery.

Comment: Okay, so why exactly can you not use it within localhost?

Comment: SAME-origin policy.

Comment: I would only suggest the other solution of JSONP then.

Comment: By the wya, I used $.ajax call with dataType of JSONP. So it works. My problem now is how can I trigger a function if the link response with 404.

Comment: You could just call a function every time you make the call, checking against the results status code (status.code !== 404) then handle your image, otherwise do nothing or a throw a error?